# Reading binary file in Java

Tags: java

Let's say I want to read a binary file which contains three of data types char, int and double (However,this binary file can contain any number of these three data types in any order.). And then I want to store three of these data types to char array list, double array list and integer array list. Anyone could be able to help? I really appreciate it.

Comment: What for do you need this?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov What difference does it make? There are plenty of binary file formats out there, and they all need reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file needs some kind of map on how to read it. There is no magic function that can distinguish between lets say 4 char and 1 int.

You need to open the file, read the map then read the file accordingly

Comment: What exactly do you mean by map?

Comment: You need a place in your file that says "3 chars in a row, then 2 ints in a row, then a double, then 2 more chars" and so on

Comment: @SHAWNNN Use `Channels` :D

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is DataInputStream. It has methods to read all the primitive datatypes. When you read which type is of course up to you :-)